# Reading meta and starting playback of m4a-files is very slow on Android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, m4a

I use MediaMetadataRetriever to retrieve meta data from m4a-files on Android device. Here is the code I execute.

```
final MediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
mmr.setDataSource(new File(root, audioFile).getAbsolutePath());

String title = mmr.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_TITLE);
String album = mmr.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM);
String artist = mmr.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST);

mmr.release();
```

The problem is that when I call this code for an mp3-files, it is very fast. For instance, 25 *mp3-files* get analysed in *under 900ms* time.

But if I call it for a single *m4a-file*, then the same code requires ***6 seconds*** to execute. And this is very slow.

Another observation is, when I use Android MediaPlayer then any mp3 file starts playing immediately, while between starting m4a-file and first sound there is same 6 seconds delay.

I tried with different Android versions and different devices. There is same issue.

Is there any way to get rid of this delay?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever](https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever):

```
final FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever();
mmr.setDataSource(new File(root, audioFile).getAbsolutePath());

String title = mmr.extractMetadata(FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_TITLE);
String album = mmr.extractMetadata(FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ALBUM);
String artist = mmr.extractMetadata(FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST);

mmr.release();
```

Comment: I looked at it but didn't want to have another native library in the app as for now. If there is no better solution I might come back to that option.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [MediaStore](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.html)?

Kindly test the speed of the MP4 file in concern by using MediaStore. A sample can be found [over here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/Media/ListtheMediaStore.htm)